# Struts 2 URL error

Tags: struts2, struts2-namespace

This is my `struts config file`:
The root of my project is **StrutsProject**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
 <package name="first" namespace="/helloworld" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="HelloWorld" class="com.abc.actions.HelloWorldAction">
   <result name="SUCCESS">/pages/login.jsp</result>
  </action>
 </package>
</struts>
```

I am trying to access the following URL:
`http://localhost:8080/StrutsProject/helloworld/HelloWorld.action`

I am getting the following error:

```
There is no Action mapped for action name helloworld. - [unknown location]
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:186)
 at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:41)
 at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:497)
 at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
```

Please help,
Siddharth

Comment: Do you get any errors on start up?  Where is your struts.xml file?

Comment: I have the struts.xml in my src folder, which is copied to WEB-INF/classes folder when I built it.
I don't get any error on start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your JSP file location is correct??

```
/pages/login.jsp
```

Or It should be

```
/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp
```